# Smart contract frameworks with different solidity versions

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I have created a smart contract that relies on Openzeppelin (solidity >=0.6.0 <0.8.0) and Moneylegos (solidity ^0.5.0). I was wondering what version I should specify on truffle, in order to get the contract compiled. Now it is giving the following error:

Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.7.4, but one or more of your contracts specify "pragma solidity ^0.5.0".
Please update your truffle config or pragma statement(s).

Comment: It is not supported to have multiple solc versions: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/2021.

Comment: Multiple solc-version support should be landing in truffle soon. Follow https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/pull/3417 for progress updates.